# Reconciling the notions of $\Delta G$ as a criterion of spontaniety and as the maximum non-expansion work

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, physical-chemistry

For a closed system that stays at constant temperature and pressure, regulated by the envrionment acting as a reservoir, it can be proven that
$$\Delta S^\text{Univ} \geq 0  \iff  0 \geq \Delta G,$$
with the inequalities saturating for reversible processes, as long as the system can only do compression-expansion work ("PV work").

If the system can also do or receive another type of work, usually (but not that accurately) called *useful* work $w_\text{use}$. As $\Delta\mathcal{U}=q+w_{PV}+w_\text{use}$ by virtue of the $1$st law, the same proof leads to
$$\Delta S^\text{Univ} \geq 0 \iff w_\text{use} \geq \Delta G.$$
Usually, it is said that a physical process or a chemical reaction is spontaneous whenever $0\geq\Delta G$ and that $\Delta G$ is the minimum useful work that can be done on the system —which is to say, the maximum useful work that can be done by the system—. But these two proofs assume incompatible hypotheses.

How is it that most web pages and basic textbooks satate both as being true at the same time? Are they really and I'm just missing something, or are they not?

NOTE: There are similar questions here in the Physics Stackexchange, but none of their answers give an answer to this, specifically. None of the ones I have read, at least.

Comment: The condition should correctly read $W_{ non-PV}\leq -\Delta G$

Comment: It does, just not with your notation, @ChetMiller. I have defined $w_\text{use}=w-w_{PV}$ and I have defined it as being applied to the system, so multiplying the equation times $-1$ yields yours.

Comment: Oh, I. thought the OP was focusing on the work done *by* the system.

Comment: Indeed, the phrasing wasn't clear, @Chet Miller. Thank you for making me notice this, I just to edited the question it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

The Gibbs free energy ($G\equiv U-TS+PV$, with internal energy $U$, temperature $T$, entropy $S$, pressure $P$, volume $V$) is a [Legendre transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) of $U$ that's meant to aid problem-solving (including the central problem of thermodynamics, identifying the equilibrium state) when the system sits in an environment of essentially constant pressure and temperature—as we and our familiar systems all do in regular life.

Put simply, that Gibbs free energy is the amount of energy we need to create the system (with internal energy $U$) **and** to push the environment out of the way to provide room for it (work $PV$) while collecting the benefit of the environment heating it to its current temperature (heat $TS$).

Thus, the Gibbs free energy incorporates only one type of work: pressure–volume work. Other types of work (surface energy work, chemical work, electrical work, magnetic work, gravitational potential work) must be explicitly stated or added; this is why a "0" appears in one context (pressure–volume work only) and "$w_\text{use}$" appears in another context (all types of work).

You are, of course, free to define the "Pablo potential" $\Pi\equiv U-TS+PV-\sigma A$, for example, for systems at constant temperature, pressure, and surface tension $\sigma$ (with the surface area $A$ free to vary) and then to write $0\ge\Delta\Pi$ as the condition of spontaneity for these systems.

Does this get at what you're asking about?

Comment: Thanks a lot! No, it does not, I'm afraid I might have phrased it wrongly. My question was if, when a chemical reaction (for instance) can do some non-PV work, why is the criterion for its spontaneity often still shown to be $\Delta G \leq 0$.

Comment: Can you refer me to an example?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that your system is coupled to two reservoirs, to an entropy reservoir at temperature $T^0$ and to a volume reservoir at pressure $p^0$. Then according to the $1^{st}$ law of thermodynamics
$$E_1+T^0S^0 = E_2 +W + p^0(V_2-V_1) \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where the indices $k=1,2$ refer to start and end states for which $E_k$ is the internal energy and $V_k$ is the volume of the system, $T^0S^0$ is the absorbed thermal energy from the entropy reservoir. The work delivered by the system is $W$ and it does not include the pressure work $p^0(V_2-V_1)$ that is lost to (absorbed by) the volume reservoir (atmosphere).  According to the $2^{nd}$ law $$ S_2-S_1 \ge S^0\tag{2}\label{2}$$ therefore denoting by $\sigma= S_2-S_1-S^0 \ge 0$ the irreversibly generated entropy in the system you get

$$W=E_1+T^0S^0 - E_2 - p^0(V_2-V_1) \\
= E_1 - E_2 +T^0(S_2-S_1-\sigma) -p^0(V_2-V_1)$$ or
$$W+T^0\sigma = E_1 - E_2 - T^0(S_1-S_2) +p^0(V_1-V_2)\tag{3}\label{3}$$
Define the process availability (exergy) $A$ *referenced* to the reservoirs  by $A=E-T^0S+p^0V$, then
$$W+T^0\sigma = A_1 - A_2 = \Delta A\tag{4}\label{4}.$$ Since $\sigma\ge0$ you get that the delivered work does not exceed the loss of availability $$W \le \Delta A \tag{5}\label{5}.$$

If the process is at constant pressure and constant temperature equal to that of the reservoirs, $T=T^0,p=p^0$, then $G=A$ and the useful work does not exceed the decrease of the Gibbs potential $W\le \Delta G$.

In all cases, equality holds if and only if the process is reversible, that is when $\sigma = 0$.